# Set current time and date as default in django model

Tags: django, django-models, orm, python-datetime

How can I set the default value as current date and time in a model?

my model is :

```
class StudUni(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uni_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

[For more info you can check here:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: this solution is fine but its not the time zone I am using, may you tell me how to change it to IST

Answer (score 0):

```
class StudUni(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uni_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
```

This will set the current date and time whenever its saved

Comment: Also instead of auto_now_add you can use auto_now=True . This will let you update the date whenever you call the save function

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you adding two timestamps, one (`date_created`) to save the date the object is created (for once) and the other one (`date_updated` or `last_updated`) to keep track on updates:

try this code below:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

[..]

class StudUni(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uni_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)

    # timestamps
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'), auto_now=True)
```

Comment: May you explain what _('date created') is doing in models.DateTimeField()

Comment: this solution is fine but its not the time zone I am using, may you tell me how to change it to IST